# IdentityServer4 Authorization failed with global authorization policy

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-authorization

I have set up an API that acts both as an authentication / authorization service, and at the same time, exposes some endpoints for data retrieval.

The API is set up with IdentityServer4. I can succesfully retrieve an access token through client credentials. However, when i attempt to call the protected endpoint with the retrieved token, i recieve a 404 not found. The log shows that the request is unauthorized.

I suspect it has something to do with the way I add the authorization policy. It should be applied globally to all controllers, with the default authentication scheme that i apply in `AddAuthentication()`, as so:

```
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => 
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.Audience = "identityService";
    }).AddMvc(options => 
    {
       var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
          .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
          .Build();

       options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    }
    ...
```

If if remove the policy, i can call the endpoint in question, without any problems.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

1. In the client credentials flow there is no user. The token doesn't contain a `sub` claim. That's why there is no authenticated user. This explains the Unauthorized error, which has HttpStatusCode 401.
2. The filter forces [authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple) *for all methods*. When a method is accessed by an unauthorized user, this will result in a HttpStatusCode 404. This means that certain methods have to remain available for anonymous users. You can exclude methods from global authorization by setting the `AllowAnonymous` attribute on the *lowest* level.

E.g. HomeController:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Error()
{
```

For the client credentials flow you may want to change the filter to something that is part of the token, like a scope:

```
var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireClaim("scope", "MyScope").Build();
```

Though that may not be suitable as a global filter when you are mixing functionality (from IdentityServer and the Api).

Instead you can configure policies and use attributes. In startup:

```
Services.AddAuthorization(option =>
{
    option.AddPolicy("MyScopePolicy", p => p.RequireScope("MyScope"));
}
```

And in the controller:

```
[Authorize("MyScopePolicy")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
```

Comment: I added the custom policy and added it to the controller, however, it still returns 404

Comment: Is the request still unauthorized?

Comment: Yes, the request is still unauthorized. Are there any specific parts of the code that i can add to my original post for you to review, or do you need something more broad?

Comment: Did you verify the token? I use this site https://jwt.io/ to see what claims are available.

Comment: I decoded the token, and it seems that both the client id and the claims (scopes) are correct

Comment: Did you add app.UseAuthentication(); to the startup.Configure?

Comment: Yes, i did. After a few searches, i'm wondering whether or not this issue has something to do with the fact that it is the same project that issues tokens and verifies them. I read something about net core 2.2 having released some integration options for this exact issue, in the case of identity server

Comment: IdentityServer is not configured as an api. I think that's the main problem. So perhaps you should start with seperate projects in order to make it work. And perhaps merge them later.